# Split String To New line using word in C# win forms

Tags: c#, string

I have big String and i want To split it with Word and make it to new line like this

> exmp: Started several mistake joy say painful removed reached end aa/
> State burst think end are its. Arrived off she elderly aaa/ beloved
> him affixed noisier yet

and i want to split it with aaa/ before aaa/ i need new line i tried this code but don't work as i expected

```
 bolo.Split(new string[] { "aaa/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: So basically you want to [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) `"aaa/"` with `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: Do you want a split or replace something with "new line"? Please show  your expected output.

Comment: How did it not "work as expected", what did you expect? Note that `.Split` doesn't update `bolo` but returns a string *array*

Comment: You have "end aa/ State" (double a) in your text, not (what I would expect) "end aaa/ State" (triple a) - a typo in your post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple and easy code:

```
string bigText = "TEstTEstTEst aaa/ TEstTEstTEst aaa/ ";
string newText = bigText.Replace(("aaa/", Enviroment.NewLine);
newText = aaa/ + newText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitStr = bolo.Split(new string[] { "aa/" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //split with aa/ first
var joinedStr = string.Join(string.Empty, splitStr); //convert the split array back to a string
var splitStr2 = joinedStr.Split(new string[] { "aaa/" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //split with aaa/
```

Answer (score -1):

bolo.replace("aaa/", Enviroment.NewLine + "aaa/");